# Search for ID name in text file and change corresponding value

Tags: vb.net

So I have a text document with the following contents:

> Brock Lesnar:Male:25
>   Braden Putt:Male:30
>   Roman Reigns:Male:37

I also have three buttons on the form.

- When the user clicks the first button, I would like the application to find the 'ID' called "Brock Lesnar" then change the age value (25) to 26.
- When the user clicks the second button, I would like the application to find the 'ID' called "Braden Putt" then change the age value (30) to 31.
- When the user clicks the third button, I would like the application to find the 'ID' called "Roman Reigns" then change the age value (37) to 38.

I have the following code as the click event for the first button. However, there are two problems. #1: It only seems to be reading the first line, as when I change `Dim idToFind` to `= "Braden Putt"`, it doesn't seem to do anything. I want it to read all the lines in the text file to find the correct ID. And #2: For some reason, it is splitting the values with commas (,) instead of colons (:).

```
Dim idToFind = "Brock Lesnar"
Dim newAge = "26"
Dim lines = IO.File.ReadAllLines(filepath)
For i = 0 To lines.Length - 1
    Dim line = lines(i)
    Dim fields = line.Split(":"c)
    If fields.Length > 2 Then
        Dim id = fields(0)
        If id = "Brock Lesnar" Then
            Dim gender = fields(1)
            lines(i) = String.Format("{0},{1},{2}", id, gender, newAge)
            Exit For
        End If
    End If
Next
IO.File.WriteAllLines(filepath, lines)
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: For #1, `If id = "Brock Lesnar"` should be `If id = idToFind`. For #2, _"For some reason it is splitting the values with commas instead of colons"_ Because that's exactly what you told it to do (particularly in `String.Format("{0},{1},{2}",...`). You should replace the commas with colons.

Comment: Thank you very much! Got issue #1 sorted. Still have problem #2 however. I have replaced the commas with colons but it still outputs into the text file with Brock Lesnar, Male, 31, etc. I have no idea why its outputting commas instead of colons.

Comment: lines(i) = String.Format("{0}:{1}:{2}", id, gender, newAge) - is this not what it should be?

Comment: Yes, that's right. And it should work. Please double-check and also make sure that the input file has the right format (i.e., it's not messed up by previous runs). After doing so **and making sure the input file doesn't actually have commas** and if the problem persists, you can [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54274343/edit) and include your new code. I'm pretty sure you won't need to do that though. Good luck!

Comment: Got it working, thank you! Just one more thing - how would i go about adding a number to newAge? Instead of just replacing it.  (Eg 26 + 1)

Comment: You can get the current age value the same way you're getting the id and gender (i.e., `fields(2)`). After doing that, you can convert it to an integer (look into [`Integer.TryParse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse)). Once you have it as an integer, you can simply create and initialize the `newAge` variable using something like `Dim newAge As Integer = oldAge + 1`.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! Got it working perfectly :-)